# Any specific case when Python >3.6.1 dict() is not ordered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

From Python version 3.6.1, dict() is ordered.

However the devs specifically warn to do not rely on this. Why? I really would like to rely on dictionaries being ordered.

I tested it over and over and I can't find any unexpected behaveior, the keys are always ordered. Am I missing something? Is there any particular case I should be aware of and I should absolutely not rely on the order of keys in dict()?

Comment: Why not just use an ordered dict?

Comment: @Dschoni to my understanding, dict() is faster than OrderedDict()

Comment: Could you provide a link for the first two statements?

Comment: @FlyingTeller https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npw4s1QTmPg

Comment: @jpp I think my question is different. I am not asking the details of the implementation, but whether I can rely on the order or not, if not, are there specific cases I should be aware of etc...

Comment: @alec_djinn, the first answer gives a detailed explanation: 
Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+? => They are insertion ordered. The second answer has more detail on your question.

Comment: @jpp ok, indeed I am satisfied with the answers given on that post. Thanks for sharing.